# Question about an attempt to print all permutations of a given list

Tags: python

I just wanted to find out what is the reason that the python shell doesn't give the output i expect for the following recursive code:

```py
def permutator(list,track):
    if len(list)==1:
        track.append(list[0])
        print (track)
    else:      
        for n in range(len(list)):
            track.append(list[n])
            return permutator(list[:n]+list[n+1:],track)
```

I expect this script to print all permutations of a given list when the variable ''track'' is initiallized as an empty list ([]); for example, i expected `permutator([1,2],[])` to print `[1,2]` and `[2,1]`. But it prints only `[1,2]`... and it really dissapointed me, since it took me a lot of time to concieve of the idea to treat the permutator function as function of two variable instead of one, in such a way that the track "documents" the recursion process (the sequential iterative process) until one arrives at a permutation of the original list.

So what is my mistake? is it fundamental (so the whole idea of the code is wrong...) or maybe there is only a small variation i need to do in order for it to start working?

I really tried to achieve success on this problem on my own but i have given up, so every help will be blessed!

Comment: It's fundamental. There's nothing in your code that could possibly **change order** of elements of `list` (BTW, using `list` as a variable name is a bad idea).

Comment: First, you're returning on the very first iteration of the loop, so the whole loop will terminate along with the function, and thus has the same effect as setting `n = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `return` the function ends and the rest of the loop never executes. Also, you don't want to append to the list becuase that effects the list that gets passed to the functions called later - instead just pass the list as it would be after appending as an argument. Specifically here, since you just want to print values, there's no need to return, so you can do:

```
def permutator(list,track):
    if len(list)==1:
        track.append(list[0])
        print (track)
    else:      
        for n in range(len(list)):
            permutator(list[:n]+list[n+1:],track + [list[n]])
```

If you decide you want to return all permutations instead of printing them, the change is easy enough:

```
def permutator(list,track):
    if len(list)==1:
        return track + [list[0]]
    else:
        perms = []
        for n in range(len(list)):
            perms.append(permutator(list[:n]+list[n+1:],track + [list[n]]))
        return perms
```

Comment: Thanks so much! i'm new to python so i didn't know that when it returns the loop ends and the rest of the loop never executes... anyway the magic i wanted to happen did happened and your code really works (obviously i voted your answer). Thanks!